# Asynchronous Functions - Is this 'callback hell'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm learning more and more about node and the biggest problem I'm having is figuring out truly how asynchronous functions work.

```
fs.readdir(base, function (err, files) {
    if (!files.length) {
        console.log('No files');
    }
    for (var i in files) {
        fs.stat(files[i], function (err, stats) {
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(files[i]);
                console.log('FOLDER');
            } else {
                console.log(files[i]);
                console.log('FILE')
            }
        })
    }
});
```

`base` is a folder with two sub-folders in, and a .DS_Store file. The output at the command line will be:

```
.DS_Store
FILE
/dir/to/file/index.js:115
      if (stats.isDirectory()) {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDirectory' of undefined
```

My basic understanding now is this problem exists because it's all happening asynchronously - my best guess is that the `readdir` callback doesn't 'wait' for the `fs.stat` callback to finish? I might be completely misunderstanding it (and really, any good documents to learn from this a base understanding would be helpful).

My next idea is something like promises? They seem to fix many problems with async so that would be my next leap in learning.

Is this 'callback hell'? Are promises the fix? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: you can use promise to get fix or you can use different approach in this article. Please go through in detail. http://justincalleja.com/2015/03/08/sequential-control-flow-with-lodash-or-underscore/#The_approach

Comment: No, the problem here seems to be hat there is an error "statting" one of the files, so `stats` will not be set. You should only access it if `err` is `null`. Solution: do proper error handling, do not ignore `err`.

Comment: (and yes, promises could solve this problem if applied correctly)

Comment: @FelixKling, I tried your option first as it was the most direct - I applied `if (!err){ .. }` but it still does the same (logs the files, folders then one 'FILE') but doesn't throw the error anymore. Still not what I need. I will move on to the other ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a couple of problems here depending on the rest of your code. One is that fs.stat takes a path as the first argument and not a filename. If you change the function call to `fs.stat(base + '/' + files[i], function (err, stats)` that might help. But I am not sure what `base` is in your example.

Secondly, you should use ES6 `let` instead of `var` in your loop. The asynchronous functions will be placed on the call stack and handled in order when they have finished. However, by that time the loop will have run all the way through and the variable `i` will be equal to its value in the last iteration. Variables defined with `let` on the other hand is limited in scope to a block, meaning that each function, since they are in separate blocks, will have the correct value of `i`.

Try testing the two different versions like below, first with `for (var i in files)` and then with `for (let i in files)`, and you will see what I mean.

```
for (var i in files) {
        fs.stat(files[i], function (err, stats) {
            if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(files[i]);
                console.log('FOLDER');
                console.log(i);
            } else {
                console.log(files[i]);
                console.log('FILE')
                console.log(i);
            }
        })
    }
```

Also, as suggested in the comments on your question I would recommend you to do proper error handling.

Comment: Thank you so much, you nailed it with the `fs.stat` requirements. I should have slowed right down and read the documents over again. You've also taught me a lesson or two!